# where does the pde's mathematical classification names come from?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

PDEs are classified into hyperbolic, parabolic and elliptic. where do these names come from? Do they have anything to do their geometric shapes?

Answer (score 3):

It's primarily due to the similarity to the corresponding algebraic equations.  For example, let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a symmetric positive definite matrix.  We say that the PDEs: 
$$
\begin{cases}
 \sum_{i,j=1}^n A_{ij} \partial_i \partial_j u =f &\text{is elliptic} \\
\partial_t u - \sum_{i,j=1}^n A_{ij} \partial_i \partial_j u =f&\text{is parabolic} \\
\partial_{t}^2 u - \sum_{i,j=1}^n A_{ij} \partial_i \partial_j u =f&\text{is hyperbolic}.
\end{cases}
$$
Similarly, we say that the algebraic equations for $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\tau \in \mathbb{R}$
$$
\begin{cases}
 \sum_{i,j=1}^n A_{ij} \xi_i \xi_j = C &\text{is elliptic} \\
\tau - \sum_{i,j=1}^n A_{ij} \xi_i \xi_j =C &\text{is parabolic} \\
\tau^2 - \sum_{i,j=1}^n A_{ij} \xi_i \xi_j =C &\text{is hyperbolic}.
\end{cases}
$$
In the latter case we say this because the solution sets are the ellipses, parabolas, and hyperbolas.

There is a deeper connection between these ideas when one uses the Fourier transform to study the above PDEs because on the Fourier side the differential operators become polynomials.

Comment: Note that the "Fourier transform" that you mean includes $t$ in the parabolic and hyperbolic cases. (Often we use a FT just in $x$, which converts certain evolution PDEs into ODEs.)

Comment: Sure.  I didn't want to elaborate too much on this technique.  You can certainly use the space-time FT for the hyperbolic problem, but for parabolic problems it's usually better to use something like the Laplace transform in the time variable.